# Detect touch on dynamically created edit text

Tags: java, android

I have an android app in which I created dynamically `EditText` in for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < materialCount; i++) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)    getActivity()..getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    ratePerUnit = (EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);
}
```

so I have to add click event on each edit text.So please tell me how to add click event on each edit text .

Comment: What do you mean by click event? What do you expect it to do basically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to give IDs to each of your `editText` to identify them separately.

for EX :

```
ratePerUnit.setId(materialCount);
```

Now, you need to implement `OnClickListener` to your `activity/fragment` and Implement the `onClick()` method in your class.

for EX :

```
class YourFragmentName extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener
{

    @Override
    void onClick(View v){
    }
}
```

Now you can set onClickLister to each of your editText in loop.

for EX:

```
ratePerUnit.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Now you will be getting click listener of your each editText in your single `onClick()` method and use the `ID` to know which editText has been clicked.

for EX:

```
@Override
void onClick(View v){
    switch(v.getId()){
       case 0:
           // editText 0 has been clicked
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I tried on same way but it detected touch on last edit text only

Comment: You need to create/instantiate ratePerUnit object every time like "rateperUnity = new EditText()" in Loop.